# Change the PDF bookmark for the table of contents page

Tags: table-of-contents, pdf, memoir, bookmarks

When I click on the PDF bookmark "Contents" in my PDF Viewer, it goes to the position of the table of contents but does not show the title "Contents". Is it possible to set the PDF bookmark above the Contents title, so one can see the title when clicking on Contents? I'm using the memoir class. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,final, oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[xetex, unicode=true, colorlinks=false, linktocpage=true, 
pdfborder={0 0 0}, pdfstartpage=1, pdfstartview=FitV, breaklinks=true,
pdfpagemode=UseNone, pageanchor=true, pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
plainpages=false, bookmarksnumbered, bookmarksopen=true,
bookmarksopenlevel=1, hypertexnames=true, pdfhighlight=/O, urlcolor=Black,
linkcolor=Black, citecolor=Black]{hyperref} 


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents 
\chapter{chapter1}
\chapter{section1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) showing your current document configuration.

Comment: Thanks! As a side note: It's usually not necessary to specify `xetex` as a driver, `hyperref` detects this automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that **memoir** puts the table of contents in the table of contents is questionable (and is the cause for the malfunction).

```
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Contents}
\tableofcontents*
```

Precede the code by `\cleardoublepage` if there's something before the ToC.